# Difference between Trace.WriteLineIf and Trace.Error

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Most examples I have found use Trace.WriteLineIf e.g.

```
       `Trace.WriteLineIf(mySwitch.TraceError,"my error");'
```

but using `Trace.TraceError("my error");` appears to give the same result (when sent to a TextWriterTraceListener).

What is the difference between the two methods ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code `Trace.WriteLineIf(mySwitch.TraceError,"my error");` will produce output only if `mySwitch.TraceError` is true, `Trace.TraceError("my error")` will produce output regardless of the value of `mySwitch.TraceError`

`Trace.TraceError` calls the TraceEvent method for each trace listener, with the trace event type Error and send a message to trace listener.

`Trace.WriteLine` and `Trace.WriteLineIf` *just* send a message to trace listener.

Consider using [TraceSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx). TraceSource is an *upgraded* Trace system.

[Edit @Robert Snyder]

Trace is still there, not marked as obsolete, so I don't have argument for not using it.
However, in big *real world* solutions I will prefer TraceSource:

- TraceSource is more *configurable*, you have better control over granularity/filtering (TraceSwitch, TraceListener), which is great when you are working with multiple assemblies.
- It is easier to trace additional information, call stack, thread information...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163767.aspx

Take a look at John Robbins article for more details:

Comment: I like too that you pointed to TraceSource, but I have been playing with it a little bit and haven't found it to be easier or better than Trace. For instance I like the indent feature which might not be available for TraceSource. I also don't like that it doesn't have a WriteLine(object) or similar. I don't see the Fail option. Can you maybe expand on why TraceSource is upgraded, and how it goes the extra mile?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main difference here is that Trace.writeLineIf will right if ANY boolean condition is met.

e.g. 
Trace.writeLineIf(condition = True, "Condition met")

I think the pattern you describe above maybe an 'abuse' of Trace.WriteLineIf but I am willing to bo told otherwise

See [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.writelineif.aspx)